# how do I delete (not exclude) a menu item from navigation bar

Tags: menus, api

I'm building a site's navigation bar programmatically, using the following code:

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' =>  $page_data->post_title,
    'menu-item-classes' => 'main',
    'menu-item-url' => '/', 
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
```

this adds menu items to my navigation bar and works well. I use this to pre-populate a number of menu items when site is created.

The question is **how do I delete a menu item from the nav menu**? (for example if user wants different menu items in the nav bar).
I know that I can use exclude, but that doesn't seem like the right solution since I don't want to constantly manage the exclude list based on user changes.

another question: how do I change menu order via code?

thanks!

Comment: you want to remove it completely from database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the menu Items are stored as a post type. Not sure but I think we can use [`wp_delete_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post) to programmatically remove it. That will completely remove the menu item from database, So you cant ever have that menu item again.

Comment: wp_delete_nav_menu_item() is coming but thanks for this solution.