# Apply a filter only once

Tags: filters, actions

I want to remove automatically the *Home* menu item, **but only once**, more precisely **at the first run of Wordpress or at the first child theme activation/loading**. Now I have a function in the functions.php of my child theme that checks if the *Home* menu item exists and delete it from the menu. Of course, this function runs every time when Wordpress loads. **How to make it to run only once?** I tried the `add_filter_once()`  function, but I got only a `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_filter_once()`.

```
function filter_wp_nav_menu_objects( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) { 

    foreach( $sorted_menu_items as $data ) {
        if ( in_array( "menu-item-home", $data->classes ) ) {
            wp_delete_post( $data->ID );
        }
    }

    return $sorted_menu_items;
} 

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'filter_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Why? What has deleting a post to do with this?

Comment: @kero https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60873/25187

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know that. And what is the problem with running the filter "every time"?

Comment: @kero Is not needed more than once (not efficient / productive).

Comment: did you try:
    add_action("after_switch_theme", "mytheme_do_something");

Comment: The problem I see here is: You don't know, which `wp_nav_menu()` call you are looking for. There can be several (and usually there are). So either you could save some config option, once you found it and removed it, set that option. But still, you'd need to add your filter to each run as to see if that option is set (and unset it on theme change, etc). I wouldn't mind the efficiency, your frontend should be served from cache anyway, and this isn't a too expensive task for an admin user to handle performance wise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native WordPress hook called `add_filter_once()`. This is an custom solution which will help you to run your hook only once.

For example if inside a loop or whatever situation you are facing. However,
The basic idea is to check when you need to stop using your hook and simply **remove_hook** from WordPress and once all done, you need to registere it again.

example code:

```
function add_filter_once( $hook, $callback, $priority = 10, $args = 1 ) {
    $singular = function () use ( $hook, $callback, $priority, $args, &$singular ) {
        call_user_func_array( $callback, func_get_args() );
        remove_filter( $hook, $singular, $priority );
    };

    return add_filter( $hook, $singular, $priority, $args );
}
```

The best way to understand what I try to explain to visit this [link](https://gist.github.com/stevegrunwell/c8307af5b88310ac1c49f6fa91f62bcb)

Comment: Overall this is good, however, for filters you need to return the value of the callback. You also need to move the `$args` argument to the `add_filter` call, instead of the `remove_filter`

Comment: If you're removing $args from the remove_filter call then you don't need it in the using() list either.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly but working way to accomplish this would be to have an `global` array, and inside your filter callback, you would check if the array already contains the hook name of the filter, you only want to apply once. If it turns out, that the value is already set, the callback will immediately return the input.

Technically, your filter will run every time, but the logic won't be applied each time, since it will skip for the 2nd execution and up.

This technique also works for class based filters, which somehow are not treated equally by WordPress, for example removing a class based filter is some sort of mess.

```php
    // … inside a class

    public function addMyFilter()
    {
        add_filter('some_filter', [$this, 'someMethod']);
    }

    public function someMethod($val)
    {
        global $myFiltersThatWhereExecAlready;

        if (empty($myFiltersThatWhereExecAlready)) {
            $myFiltersThatWhereExecAlready = [];
        }

        if (in_array(__METHOD__, $myFiltersThatWhereExecAlready)) {
            return $val;
        }

        $myFiltersThatWhereExecAlready[] = __METHOD__;

        // … doing your filtering
    }
```